# Android application using web service is running on emulator, but not in device

Tags: java, android

Sir,
    I have developed an application to read data from external mysql database.
For that I am using SOAP.Apache Tomcat server is loaded in my system(localhost).So application is working in emulator.But in real device it is not working.My administrator has provided me one public IP.Instead of localhost I have used that public IP.So from outside(mobile browser),the wsdl file is opening,but application is not running.

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Please post your logcat if you get any error/exceptions

Comment: post your logcat , put the code where you have mentioned URL , is there any localhost ??